# parametrize function angular chemicals

Tags: angular

i have these 2 functions and I want to make a parametrized function with chemical input like this

```
 clearCancerDropdown() {
        this.cancerDropdown.clear();
      }

      clearReproductiveDropdown() {
        this.reproductiveDropdown.clear();
      }
```

and I want to make a parametrized function with chemical input like this

```
 clearDropdown(chemical) {
        switch (chemical) {
          case cancer:
            this.cancerDropdown.clear();
            break;

     case cancer:
             this.reproductiveDropdown.clear();
            break;

          default:
            break;
        }
}


  clearCancerDropdown() {
    this.cancerDropdown.clear();
  }

  clearReproductiveDropdown() {
    this.reproductiveDropdown.clear();
```

the problem is that chemical is sent like this

```
this.checkChemical(this.itemFlags.cancer);
```

and itemFlag interface looks like this

```
export interface ItemFlags {
    exempt: boolean;
    cancer: boolean;
    reproductive: boolean;
}
```

what my code does right now - verifies if boolean == cancer and it's not correct
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**Option 1:**

Use simple `if-else` statements to check the type of itemFlag.

```js
checkChemical(itemFlags: ItemFlags) {
  if (itemFlags.cancer) {
    // Logic for Cancer case
  } else if (itemFlags.reproductive) {
    // Logic for Reproductive case
  } else if (itemFlags.exempt) {
    // Logic for Exempt case
  }
}
```

The caller method should pass the entire object of itemFlags, as shown below:

```js
// Perform your logic for initalizaing itemFLags
this.itemFlags = { cancer: true; reproductive: false; exempt: false };
// Pass the entire object to the method
this.checkChemical(this.itemFlags);
```

**Option 2:**

If you are not a big fan of `if-else` statements, you can use `switch` statements but for that you should change your interface to enum.

**item-flags.model.ts**

```js
export enum ItemFlags {
  CANCER = 'cancer',
  REPRODUCTIVE = 'reproductive',
  EXEMPT = 'exempt'
}
```

**Component/Service file:**

```js
checkChemical(itemFlags: ItemFlags) {
  switch(itemFlags) {
    case ItemFlags.CANCER:
      // Logic for Cancer case
      break;
    case ItemFlags.REPRODUCTIVE:
      // Logic for Reproductive case
      break;
    case ItemFlags.EXEMPT:
      // Logic for Exempt case
      break;
    default:
      // Default case
  }
}
```

Now in the caller method, call the checkChemical method as shown below:

```js
// CANCER case
this.checkChemical(ItemFlags.CANCER);
// REPRODUCTIVE case
this.checkChemical(ItemFlags.REPRODUCTIVE);
// EXEMPT case
this.checkChemical(ItemFlags.EXEMPT);
```

Make sure to import the ItemFlags enum if it is in a different file.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the itemFlag and then check if itemFlag.cancer or itemFlag.reproductive instead of the switch